# No benefit on my MySQL partitions

Tags: mysql, sql, database-partitioning

I've the follow SQL schema on my MySQL server `5.7.20`:

```
CREATE TABLE `partitioned_products` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `description` text,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
PARTITION BY HASH (id) PARTITIONS 10;

CREATE TABLE `not_partitioned_products` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `description` text,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `partitioned_product_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `index_partitioned_product_values_on_id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_partitioned_product_values_on_product_id` (`product_id`)
)
PARTITION BY HASH (product_id) PARTITIONS 10;

CREATE TABLE `not_partitioned_product_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `index_not_partitioned_product_values_on_id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_not_partitioned_product_values_on_product_id` (`product_id`)
);
```

So I've 2 couple of tables, one partitioned and the other not.
These tables are populated with over **100 millions** of records.

Now, if I perform a query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM partitioned_product_values
WHERE product_id IN (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 750, 760, 770, 780, 790, 800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880, 890, 900, 910, 920, 930, 940, 950, 960, 970, 980, 990, 1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090, 1100, 1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1160, 1170, 1180, 1190, 1200, 1210, 1220, 1230, 1240, 1250, 1260, 1270, 1280, 1290, 1300, 1310, 1320, 1330, 1340, 1350, 1360, 1370, 1380, 1390, 1400, 1410, 1420, 1430, 1440, 1450, 1460, 1470, 1480, 1490, 1500, 1510, 1520, 1530, 1540, 1550, 1560, 1570, 1580, 1590, 1600, 1610, 1620, 1630, 1640, 1650, 1660, 1670, 1680, 1690, 1700, 1710, 1720, 1730, 1740, 1750, 1760, 1770, 1780, 1790, 1800, 1810, 1820, 1830, 1840, 1850, 1860, 1870, 1880, 1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080, 2090, 2100, 2110, 2120, 2130, 2140, 2150, 2160, 2170, 2180, 2190, 2200, 2210, 2220, 2230, 2240, 2250, 2260, 2270, 2280, 2290, 2300, 2310, 2320, 2330, 2340, 2350, 2360, 2370, 2380, 2390, 2400, 2410, 2420, 2430, 2440, 2450, 2460, 2470, 2480, 2490, 2500, 2510, 2520, 2530, 2540, 2550, 2560, 2570, 2580, 2590, 2600, 2610, 2620, 2630, 2640, 2650, 2660, 2670, 2680, 2690, 2700, 2710, 2720, 2730, 2740, 2750, 2760, 2770, 2780, 2790, 2800, 2810, 2820, 2830, 2840, 2850, 2860, 2870, 2880, 2890, 2900, 2910, 2920, 2930, 2940, 2950, 2960, 2970, 2980, 2990, 3000, 3010, 3020, 3030, 3040, 3050, 3060, 3070, 3080, 3090, 3100, 3110, 3120, 3130, 3140, 3150, 3160, 3170, 3180, 3190, 3200, 3210, 3220, 3230, 3240, 3250, 3260, 3270, 3280, 3290, 3300, 3310, 3320, 3330, 3340, 3350, 3360, 3370, 3380, 3390, 3400, 3410, 3420, 3430, 3440, 3450, 3460, 3470, 3480, 3490, 3500, 3510, 3520, 3530, 3540, 3550, 3560, 3570, 3580, 3590, 3600, 3610, 3620, 3630, 3640, 3650, 3660, 3670, 3680, 3690, 3700, 3710, 3720, 3730, 3740, 3750, 3760, 3770, 3780, 3790, 3800, 3810, 3820, 3830, 3840, 3850, 3860, 3870, 3880, 3890, 3900, 3910, 3920, 3930, 3940, 3950, 3960, 3970, 3980, 3990, 4000, 4010, 4020, 4030, 4040, 4050, 4060, 4070, 4080, 4090, 4100, 4110, 4120, 4130, 4140, 4150, 4160, 4170, 4180, 4190, 4200, 4210, 4220, 4230, 4240, 4250, 4260, 4270, 4280, 4290, 4300, 4310, 4320, 4330, 4340, 4350, 4360, 4370, 4380, 4390, 4400, 4410, 4420, 4430, 4440, 4450, 4460, 4470, 4480, 4490, 4500, 4510, 4520, 4530, 4540, 4550, 4560, 4570, 4580, 4590, 4600, 4610, 4620, 4630, 4640, 4650, 4660, 4670, 4680, 4690, 4700, 4710, 4720, 4730, 4740, 4750, 4760, 4770, 4780, 4790, 4800, 4810, 4820, 4830, 4840, 4850, 4860, 4870, 4880, 4890, 4900, 4910, 4920, 4930, 4940, 4950, 4960, 4970, 4980, 4990, 5000, 5010, 5020, 5030, 5040, 5050, 5060, 5070, 5080, 5090, 5100, 5110, 5120, 5130, 5140, 5150, 5160, 5170, 5180, 5190, 5200, 5210, 5220, 5230, 5240, 5250, 5260, 5270, 5280, 5290, 5300, 5310, 5320, 5330, 5340, 5350, 5360, 5370, 5380, 5390, 5400, 5410, 5420, 5430, 5440, 5450, 5460, 5470, 5480, 5490, 5500, 5510, 5520, 5530, 5540, 5550, 5560, 5570, 5580, 5590, 5600, 5610, 5620, 5630, 5640, 5650, 5660, 5670, 5680, 5690, 5700, 5710, 5720, 5730, 5740, 5750, 5760, 5770, 5780, 5790, 5800, 5810, 5820, 5830, 5840, 5850, 5860, 5870, 5880, 5890, 5900, 5910, 5920, 5930, 5940, 5950, 5960, 5970, 5980, 5990, 6000, 6010, 6020, 6030, 6040, 6050, 6060, 6070, 6080, 6090, 6100, 6110, 6120, 6130, 6140, 6150, 6160, 6170, 6180, 6190, 6200, 6210, 6220, 6230, 6240, 6250, 6260, 6270, 6280, 6290, 6300, 6310, 6320, 6330, 6340, 6350, 6360, 6370, 6380, 6390, 6400, 6410, 6420, 6430, 6440, 6450, 6460, 6470, 6480, 6490, 6500, 6510, 6520, 6530, 6540, 6550, 6560, 6570, 6580, 6590, 6600, 6610, 6620, 6630, 6640, 6650, 6660, 6670, 6680, 6690, 6700, 6710, 6720, 6730, 6740, 6750, 6760, 6770, 6780, 6790, 6800, 6810, 6820, 6830, 6840, 6850, 6860, 6870, 6880, 6890, 6900, 6910, 6920, 6930, 6940, 6950, 6960, 6970, 6980, 6990, 7000, 7010, 7020, 7030, 7040, 7050, 7060, 7070, 7080, 7090, 7100, 7110, 7120, 7130, 7140, 7150, 7160, 7170, 7180, 7190, 7200, 7210, 7220, 7230, 7240, 7250, 7260, 7270, 7280, 7290, 7300, 7310, 7320, 7330, 7340, 7350, 7360, 7370, 7380, 7390, 7400, 7410, 7420, 7430, 7440, 7450, 7460, 7470, 7480, 7490, 7500, 7510, 7520, 7530, 7540, 7550, 7560, 7570, 7580, 7590, 7600, 7610, 7620, 7630, 7640, 7650, 7660, 7670, 7680, 7690, 7700, 7710, 7720, 7730, 7740, 7750, 7760, 7770, 7780, 7790, 7800, 7810, 7820, 7830, 7840, 7850, 7860, 7870, 7880, 7890, 7900, 7910, 7920, 7930, 7940, 7950, 7960, 7970, 7980, 7990, 8000, 8010, 8020, 8030, 8040, 8050, 8060, 8070, 8080, 8090, 8100, 8110, 8120, 8130, 8140, 8150, 8160, 8170, 8180, 8190, 8200, 8210, 8220, 8230, 8240, 8250, 8260, 8270, 8280, 8290, 8300, 8310, 8320, 8330, 8340, 8350, 8360, 8370, 8380, 8390, 8400, 8410, 8420, 8430, 8440, 8450, 8460, 8470, 8480, 8490, 8500, 8510, 8520, 8530, 8540, 8550, 8560, 8570, 8580, 8590, 8600, 8610, 8620, 8630, 8640, 8650, 8660, 8670, 8680, 8690, 8700, 8710, 8720, 8730, 8740, 8750, 8760, 8770, 8780, 8790, 8800, 8810, 8820, 8830, 8840, 8850, 8860, 8870, 8880, 8890, 8900, 8910, 8920, 8930, 8940, 8950, 8960, 8970, 8980, 8990, 9000, 9010, 9020, 9030, 9040, 9050, 9060, 9070, 9080, 9090, 9100, 9110, 9120, 9130, 9140, 9150, 9160, 9170, 9180, 9190, 9200, 9210, 9220, 9230, 9240, 9250, 9260, 9270, 9280, 9290, 9300, 9310, 9320, 9330, 9340, 9350, 9360, 9370, 9380, 9390, 9400, 9410, 9420, 9430, 9440, 9450, 9460, 9470, 9480, 9490, 9500, 9510, 9520, 9530, 9540, 9550, 9560, 9570, 9580, 9590, 9600, 9610, 9620, 9630, 9640, 9650, 9660, 9670, 9680, 9690, 9700, 9710, 9720, 9730, 9740, 9750, 9760, 9770, 9780, 9790, 9800, 9810, 9820, 9830, 9840, 9850, 9860, 9870, 9880, 9890, 9900, 9910, 9920, 9930, 9940, 9950, 9960, 9970, 9980, 9990, 10000);
```

the query on partitioned table respond in about ~12ms while the query on not partitioned table respond in ~3ms (note that the ids in where clause module 10 are 0).

If I run `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM partitioned_product_values WHERE product_id IN (0, 10, ...)`

I get:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                  | key                                            | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | partitioned_product_values | p0         | range | index_partitioned_product_values_on_product_id | index_partitioned_product_values_on_product_id | 8       | NULL | 10010 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Why the query on partitioned table is slower (same)? I would have expected a slower response time on partitioned table... If I don't get benefit on table over 100M of records why I should partition a table?

Comment: The difference between 12 milliseconds and 3 milliseconds is probably immaterial.

Comment: "Why the query on partitioned table is slower?" it not that big off a difference..Geuss it's the difference between hot and cold data... Even if you sad SQL_NO_CACHE hard disk cache will still cache data..

Comment: Ok, but I expected a slower response time on partitioned table... If I don't get benefit on table over 100M of records why I should partition a table?

Comment: partitioning isn't the magic bullet that will insure your query's will execute much faster.. "When PARTITION BY HASH is used, MySQL determines which partition of num partitions to use based on the modulus of the result of the expression. In other words, for a given expression expr, the partition in which the record is stored is partition number N, where N = MOD(expr, num): " https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.htmlhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html  that will cause some overhead

Comment: @RaymondNijland thx! So when to use partitioning?

Comment: most use: horizontal scaling, i.e. on many machines https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html Cluster can be more performant, or not (If comparable single installation is possible), No silver bullet.

Comment: Since your id is an integer, perhaps consider partitioning by range as a test. Your system won't have the CPU overhead of having to hash incoming values to determine the partition, although you will still have the overhead to hit the partitioning table before it can do the table scan. Also it sounds like you might be on a very quiet box right now. If you were having heavier I/O then the little insignificant 9ms bump that is probably coming from your CPU would be a tiny trade off to avoid a 100m+ table scan. It's a database, so it's always a balancing act (indexes, cpu, i/o, partitioning, etc)

Comment: Observation: Your partitioned query requires a multi-range read (MRR). Using that strategy to satisfy your query may generate either latency or overhead or both. Suggestion: Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON query`. You may get more details. Observation: good indexing generally outruns partititioning for improving performance. Use partititioning only in special circumstances like those mentioned by @JacekCz.